# Facebook javascript SDK connection failing in IE and Safari

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am running into a problem with logging in to Facebook on Safari and IE. I can login just fine with Chrome and Firefox with the following code:

```
        var appId = 'APP ID';
    var uid;

    // Initialize the JS SDK
    FB.init({
     appId: appId,
     status: true, // check login status
     cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
     channelUrl: '//localhost:8888/photo/channel.html' // Channel File
    });
    // Get the user's UID
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
     uid = response.authResponse.userID ? response.authResponse.userID : null;
     console.info(uid);
    });

    function authUser() {
     FB.login(function(response) {
       console.info(response);
       uid = response.authResponse.userID ? response.authResponse.userID : null;
       console.info("called");
     }, {scope:'email,publish_actions'});
```

but when my code gets to `FB.getLoginStatus` on Safari and IE the response shows

```
authResponse: undefined
status: "unknown"
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that the popup that shows the permissions is not popping up in Safari and IE.

Comment: How/where do you call your function `authUser`?

Comment: I don't call it in my code. I figured that facebook took care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the status is "unknown" that means one of two things:

1. the user is not logged in, or
2. third party cookies are disabled

Safari is the only browser to come with third-party cookies disabled by default (Firefox will be following suit shortly). Some of the higher security settings in IE will also turn them off. Since your code is working in Firefox/Chrome I would guess this is the culprit.

Unfortunately, third-party cookies are required for FB.getLoginStatus to return an appropriate authResponse and status. I think your options are pretty limited:

1. Let the user log in through PHP or another back-end SDK, and force them to sign in again every 2 hours (I think FB tokens expire every 7600 seconds)
2. Detect the "unknown" status and display a message to the user asking them to enable third-party cookies for facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually fix the problem I was able to get around it by running the app on Facebook instead of my localhost. I believe this is because when on Facebook I am already logged in.